# Parse value from json

Tags: datadog

For a log for a particular service my one attribute `httpRequest` returns a json object:

```
"httpRequest": {
    "country": "DE",
    "headers": [
        {
            "name": "Host",
            "value": "mydomain.example.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "User-Agent",
            "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0"
        },
        {
            "name": "Accept",
            "value": "image/avif,image/webp,*/*"
        },
        {
            "name": "Accept-Language",
            "value": "en,en-US;q=0.5"
        },
        {
            "name": "Accept-Encoding",
            "value": "gzip, deflate, br"
        },
        {
            "name": "Connection",
            "value": "keep-alive"
        },
        {
            "name": "Referer",
            "value": "https://mydomain.example.com/cat.jpg"
        },
        {
            "name": "Cookie",
            "value": "OptanonConsent=isIABGlobal=false&datestamp=Thu+Oct+21+2021+09%3A55%3A11+GMT%2B0200+(South+Africa+Standard+Time)&version=6.22.0&landingPath=NotLandingPage&AwaitingReconsent=false&groups=C0001%3A1%2CC0003%3A1%2CC0002%3A1%2CC0004%3A1&isGpcEnabled=0&hosts=&geolocation=ZA%3BWC; _ga_QQSC9D30C7=GS1.1.1620799882.6.0.1620799882.60; _ga=GA1.2.2133505955.1614865120; WZRK_G=79ce4c41d4194196af7e2846c4baec9b; ajs_anonymous_id=%227acfac50-a8df-4199-921c-eb149f78cd8d%22; OptanonAlertBoxClosed=2021-10-21T07:55:10.937Z"
        },
        {
            "name": "Sec-Fetch-Dest",
            "value": "image"
        },
        {
            "name": "Sec-Fetch-Mode",
            "value": "no-cors"
        },
        {
            "name": "Sec-Fetch-Site",
            "value": "same-origin"
        },
        {
            "name": "Pragma",
            "value": "no-cache"
        },
        {
            "name": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "no-cache"
        }
    ],
    "args": "",
    "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1"
}
```

What I am trying to do is parse the `headers` section so that I can create a new facet for the `headers.Host` value. Another thing to note is that the number of objects in this `headers` array can change, ie sometimes there will be a `X-Forwarder-for` header as an example.

To create a new attribute I've tried to use the String builder processor - but it looks like that won't work on an array. I've tried having a target value of `%{httpRequest.headers.Host}` but that returns a null value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter method:

```js
const req={"httpRequest": { "country": "DE", "headers": [ { "name": "Host", "value": "mydomain.example.com" }, { "name": "User-Agent", "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0" }, { "name": "Accept", "value": "image/avif,image/webp,*/*" }, { "name": "Accept-Language", "value": "en,en-US;q=0.5" }, { "name": "Accept-Encoding", "value": "gzip, deflate, br" }, { "name": "Connection", "value": "keep-alive" }, { "name": "Referer", "value": "https://waftestcdn.getsmarter.com/cat.jpg" }, { "name": "Cookie", "value": "OptanonConsent=isIABGlobal=false&datestamp=Thu+Oct+21+2021+09%3A55%3A11+GMT%2B0200+(South+Africa+Standard+Time)&version=6.22.0&landingPath=NotLandingPage&AwaitingReconsent=false&groups=C0001%3A1%2CC0003%3A1%2CC0002%3A1%2CC0004%3A1&isGpcEnabled=0&hosts=&geolocation=ZA%3BWC; _ga_QQSC9D30C7=GS1.1.1620799882.6.0.1620799882.60; _ga=GA1.2.2133505955.1614865120; WZRK_G=79ce4c41d4194196af7e2846c4baec9b; ajs_anonymous_id=%227acfac50-a8df-4199-921c-eb149f78cd8d%22; OptanonAlertBoxClosed=2021-10-21T07:55:10.937Z" }, { "name": "Sec-Fetch-Dest", "value": "image" }, { "name": "Sec-Fetch-Mode", "value": "no-cors" }, { "name": "Sec-Fetch-Site", "value": "same-origin" }, { "name": "Pragma", "value": "no-cache" }, { "name": "Cache-Control", "value": "no-cache" } ], "args": "", "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1" }}

console.log(req.httpRequest.headers.filter((el)=>el.name==='Host')[0].value)
```